# Automate status checkbox to verify active/inactive

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I wish to automate a scenario, where in a data grid I have a checkbox for Status for a user, whether the user is active or not, now what I am doing is:

**1.** Creating a list of checkboxes on the Grid, and if the size > 0 then I gettext() of the first record in the grid and store it in a string variable.

**2.** Send the data of the string variable in the search-box and the user appears, now I click the checkbox and if it is inactive then it becomes active, and vice-versa.

Now I want to verify that the checkbox gets selected/clicked and the status changes on click, but not sure how do I verify it, that an active becomes inactive and vice-versa.

Can someone please suggest how do I go about this scenario?

`<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onclick="activeChange(this)" id="chkIsActive_6" checked="checked">`

**When Checkbox is selected or the user is "Active""**

`<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onclick="activeChange(this)" id="chkIsActive_6">`

**When Checkbox is unselected or the user is "Inactive""**

Comment: What happens when active become inactive ? Can we have HTML for both these scenarios ?

Comment: Updated the question with HTML

Comment: Well there has to be some difference in HTML DOM, when any one of them gets triggered.

Comment: There is, the checked attribute is not available when it is unchecked. So that is a change is see at least in that particular element.

Comment: In HTML where you can see the `inactive` status?

Comment: Well there is a column Status if it is checked the user is active and if not the user is inactive, hope this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different attribute between ***Active*** and ***Inactive*** element.

Actually you can achieve with `.getAttribute("checked")`, see the below approach:

```
//get current element
WebElement elementBefore = driver.findElement(By.id("chkIsActive_6"));
String before = elementBefore.getAttribute("checked");

//do something here to make the element change, maybe click event
...

//ideally insert a wait here
...

//get element after action
WebElement elementAfter = driver.findElement(By.id("chkIsActive_6"));
String after = elementAfter.getAttribute("checked");

//verify
if(!after.equals(before)) {
    //successfully changed
}
```

Comment: Absolute genius! This is what I was looking for, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try using isSelected() method:

```
isChecked = webElement.findElement(By.id("chkIsActive_6")).isSelected();
```

Comment: That won't give me an idea whether the active became inactive or vice-versa, my motive is not to verify whether the checkbox is selected or not, I want to verify whether if it was de-selected in the beginning then onClick it became selected and vice-versa